# Chaining parentNode calls

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to chain parentNode (or something similar) calls?

For example, say I have this html:

```
<div id="mainDiv">

    <div class="class1" id="id1">
        <div class="button" id="button"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="class2" id="id2">
    </div>

</div>
```

Now let's say I have an event listener on "button". Now I want to change the id="id2" to something different, say "newId", so I call this function on "click". Is it legal to do something like this?:

```
function changeIdOfItem(event) {
    var event.target.parentNode.parentNode.lastChild.id = "newId";
}
```

My logic is that the first parentNode will take you up to "id1", the second parentNode will take you up to "mainDiv", then lastChild will take you down to "id2" where you can change the id. If not this way, how would you best accomplish this with "pure" JavaScript?

Comment: Please don't change IDs of DOM elements.

Comment: `document.getElementById("id2").id = "newId";` (since `id`s are unique). And note that in your example, it's `lastChild` (capital "C"). "Is it legal to do something like this?" - yes it's "legal", and works fine, because `parentNode` returns the parent DOM node, which obviously has a `parentNode` property

Comment: Yes it is possible. Did you try ? .lastchild won't work though.But with a uppercase C, probably.

Comment: The basis of this is that I have a JS function that is reliant on a certain id to perform it's actions. So I have a bunch of what I refer to as "id2" (different ID in my actual html) and I need to reassign it\s id depending on whether that one was clicked. So if a certain div was clicked, I reassign all other ids, change the id of the clicked one to what I need, then call the appropriate function. If that makes sense..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the root of the question, yes you can chain [`Node.parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.parentNode) calls as each call is returning another `Node` with that same property exposed. Visually:

```
<div id="baz">
  <div id="bar">
    <p id="foo">Hello, world!</p>
  </div>
<div>


var el = document.getElementById('foo'); // p#foo

// traversing, route a:
var bar = el.parentNode;
var baz = bar.parentNode;

// traversing, route b:
var baz = el.parentNode.parentNode;
//          ^   #bar  ^
//                      ^  #baz  ^
```

However, it's (arguably) poor design to be changing the element's ID and, instead, I would look in to adding (or removing) a `className` instead.

Comment: I added a comment above. That might clarify why I'm doing that, though I could possibly change the JS function to rely on the classname of an item, instead of its id. Which, now that I think about it, might be a whole lot nicer...

Comment: @JordanPlahn: i agree, using class names to delegate responsibility would lend itself better. Changing IDs may not be the root of all evil, but give yourself enough lines of code and enough transfers of ID names and you could end up with duplicate IDs eventually (or investing more time than you'd like trying to avoid it).

Comment: Yep, changed it to use class names and it's so much simpler. Thanks for the smart ideas ;-).

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to chain [`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.parentNode) (or something similar) calls?

I wouldn't use the term "*call*" (like for a method of function), they're just property accesses. But yes, you can indeed nest/chain them.

> My logic is that the first `parentNode` will take you up to "id1", the second `parentNode` will take you up to "mainDiv",

Yes and yes.

> then `lastChild` will take you down to "id2"

No. The last child of that div will be the whitespace text node after the `#id2`. You could use [`.lastElementChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.lastElementChild) however.

> I want to change the id="id2" to something different, say "newId". If not this way, how would you best accomplish this with "pure" JavaScript?

You could simply directly access the div by that id:

```
var otherDiv = document.getElementById("id2");
if (otherDiv != null) // when it will have been changed once,
                      // the `#id2` selector won't get it any more
    otherDiv.id = "newId";`enter code here`
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on .lastElementchild. Don't know how I had been looking over that for the last hour. Implemented that it definitely helped as well.